# Qt connect itemDoubleClicked to self-defined slot

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have the following class that extends `QListWidget`, but I can't seem to connect the `doubleClicked` signal to the slot I desire. Here's the code implemented - in VS2012. The idea is to be able to double click a item and edit it. I connect the signal to the slot in the constructor, but the slot is never called when I run it through the debugger.

```
# .h file
class DisplayFeed :
    public QListWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DisplayFeed(QWidget *parent, Logic *logic, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, std::string color);
    ~DisplayFeed(void);
    void setColor(std::string color);
    void refresh(std::vector<Event*> *thingsToInclude);
private:
    Logic* logic;
private slots:
    void editItem(QEventStore *item);
};
```

Below is the .cpp file. `QEventStore` extends `QListWidgetItem`. I placed the MessageBox to test the system as well, in case it was my other code that didn't work.

```
# .cpp file, only relevant methods included
DisplayFeed::DisplayFeed(QWidget *parent, Logic *logic, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, std::string color)
: QListWidget(parent)
{
    this->logic = logic;
    setGeometry(xpos, ypos, width, height);
    setColor(color);
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QEventStore*)), this, SLOT(editItem(QEventStore*)));
    show();
}

void DisplayFeed::editItem(QEventStore *item){
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Hello!","You clicked \""+item->text()+"\"");
    QEventEditor *editor = new QEventEditor(item->getEvent());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The problem is that the default signal for `itemDoubleClicked` emits the `QListWidgetItem*` and emitting a subclass of that doesn't work. So what I had to do was to go to `editItem` and get it to dynamic_cast the `QListWidgetItem*` to a `QEventStore*`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your `DisplayFeed` class. It should be like :

```
# .h file
class DisplayFeed :
    public QListWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
    DisplayFeed(QWidget *parent, Logic *logic, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, std::string color);
    ~DisplayFeed(void);
    void setColor(std::string color);
    void refresh(std::vector<Event*> *thingsToInclude);
private:
    Logic* logic;
private slots:
    void editItem(QEventStore *item);
};
```

That's the first thing I noticed and may solve your problem. If not I'll look deeper.

EDIT: Read the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368584/qt-question-what-does-the-q-object-macro-do-why-do-all-qt-objects-need-this-ma)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Unfortunately this hasn't solved the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

#### There are several changes to do:

1. Add **Q_OBJECT** in the .**h** of displayFeed class

   ```
   class DisplayFeed : public QListWidget
   {
       Q_OBJECT
       ...
   };
   ```
2. Change your slot with a **public slot** and a **QListWidgetItem*** parameter

   ```
   public slots:
       void editItem(QListWidgetItem *item);
   ```
3. Connect with the good **SIGNAL** which have the same parameter that your **SLOT**

   ```
   connect(this,SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this,SLOT(editItem(QListWidgetItem*)));
   ```

This works fine for me, hope it helps you.

Comment: Sorry man. This doesn't work. There's no point switching to a QListWidgetItem when I've extended it intentionally for a reason