# Slot not getting called despite successful connect

Tags: c++, qt

I want to connect a pushbutton to a `client::prework()`. After trivial debugging I find that `client::prework()` is not being called (no portion of it is being executed), but the `QObject::connect` call returns `true`.

client.h

```
class client : public QObject
{
   //some declarations
   public slots:
   int prework();
};
```

client.cpp

```
void client::prework()
{
  //implementation

}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   QWidget * wdg = new QWidget(this);
   QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout(wdg);
   QPushButton *btn1 = new QPushButton("connectme");
   vlay->addWidget(btn1);
   client obj1;
   qDebug()<<"h";
   QObject::connect(btn1,SIGNAL(clicked()),&obj1,SLOT(prework()));
// obj1.prework();
 }
```

Comment: You have forgotten to add `Q_OBJECT` macro to the `client` declaration. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368584/qt-question-what-does-the-q-object-macro-do-why-do-all-qt-objects-need-this-ma

Comment: You declare `prework` to return `int` in the header, but in your .cpp you define it as `void`. This is a typo, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : ...
{
   ... 
   client obj1;
   ...
 } //  1
```

The line marked with `// 1` is the line where `obj1` gets destroyed. Local variables do not outlive the scope in which they were created. (And the [`QObject` destructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject) ensures that signals are disconnected.)

You need to make that object a member of your main window class if you want it to outlive the constructor.

Comment: I made the object global and it worked but is there a way i don't have to make the object global?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by global? I indicated to make it a member of your class, that's not "global" by usual definitions. If you don't want it as a member of your class (directly or as a pointer), you need to store it elsewhere and be extremely careful that it outlives the instances of your class where it is used.

Comment: you mean `obj1` should be made a member of `client` class?

Comment: @user3819404 No, he means it should be a [member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable) of the `MainWindow` class.